# what is the difference between os.environ.setdefault() vs os.environ.putenv()

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, manage.py

It is my understanding that both are supposed to set environmental variables. But toggling between these two in django's `manage.py` file leads to different outcomes.

```
>>> help(os.environ.putenv)
putenv(name, value, /)                                       
    Change or add an environment variable
```

If I edit the `manage.py` file and change `os.environ.setdefault` to `os.environ.putenv`, I get the following:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQknq.png]

**Question**: Why does `os.environ.setdefault` work in this case, but `os.environ.putenv` does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference is that `os.environ.setdefault` treats `os.environ` as a python `dict`, while `os.putenv` or `os.environ.putenv` makes changes to the environment that affect subprocesses started with `os.system()`, `os.popen()` or `os.fork()` and `os.execv()`. The documentation for [`os.putenv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os%20putenv#os.putenv) notes the following about the relationship between `os.environ` and `os.putenv`:

> Assignments to items in `os.environ` are automatically translated into
> corresponding calls to putenv(); however, calls to `putenv()` don’t
> update `os.environ`, so it is actually preferable to assign to items of
> os.environ.

Based on the above statement, updating the environment variables with `os.putenv` does not necessarily update the `os.environ` dictionary. Therefore, it comes down to how the environment variable in question is used. In the case of `Django`, the environment variable in question is accessed in the [`django/config/__init__.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/56f9579105c324ff15250423bf9f8bdf1634cfb4/django/conf/__init__.py#L47) file with the following line of code:

```
settings_module = os.environ.get(ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
```

Clearly, this line is treating `os.environ` as a dictionary. Since changes made using `os.putenv` don't affect this `os.environ` dictionary, `django` is not able to find the settings module (i.e. the `settings_module` variable is equal to `None`).

In sum, if you want to update environment variables, it's more encompassing to use `os.environ['VARIABLE'] = 'VALUE'` or `os.environ.setdefault`. Because, as mentioned above, updating the `os.environ` both updates the dictionary and also calls `os.putenv`.

Comment: does using `os.environ.setdefault` or `os.environ['VARIABLE'] = 'VALUE'` make permanent entries to System environment variables or is it for program runtime only?

Comment: `os.environ.setdefault` and `os.environ['VARIABLE'] = 'VALUE'` only impact the running program and any child processes the running program creates. I am not exactly sure what you mean by system environment variables, the changes only apply to the running program and its children.